# SAT math problem about probability

Tags: probability

A drawer contains $3$ purple crayons and $5$ red crayons. What is the probability that you select two purple crayons if you reach in the drawer and randomly grab two crayons without replacement?

Answer: $\frac{3}{28}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is: (The probability that the first crayon is purple) $\times$ (The probability that the second crayon is purple assuming that you drew a purple the first time).

That is $$\frac{3}{8} \times \frac{2}{7} = \frac{3}{28}$$

Answer (score 4):

First one you reach for it the probability it will be $\color{purple}{purple}$ is $$\color{purple}{\frac{3}{8}}$$

Because you divide the number of purple crayons over the total number of crayons.

Now $7$ crayons are left, and $2$ of them are purple assuimung that you get the first one purple and so the probability of the second one being $\color{purple}{purple}$ is $$\color{purple}{\frac{2}{7}}$$

And now just multiply the two fractions to get your answer as $$\color{purple}{\frac{3}{28}}$$

Comment: Upvoted because of the color. :)

Comment: thanks :) @FundThmCalculus

Answer (score 2):

Probability = $\frac{favorable -events}{total -events}$

In this case number of favorable events = $^3C_2$ (select any 2 purple crayons out of the three)

Number of total events = $^8C_2$(select any 2 crayons out of the total 8)